# How do I get a moderator's attention?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

I have a question about the bounty I put on one of my recent questions. I added the following comment underneath the question:

> Mods: i just answered my own bounty question...do i get my bounty back? If not, can i give the bounty to the member that i found my answer from.

I was hoping that a mod would see the comment and give me an answer, but I haven't gotten a response.

Comment: You've got their attention now...

Comment: [What is a bounty?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) => "**All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**"

Comment: See also [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: No, moderators don't read all edits on questions, nor do they read all comments on questions. Stack Overflow has too much volume for this to be even remotely feasible.

Comment: I assumed that they would have some 'website scrapping' program going around looking for the word "mod" or "moderator" .. but that's just how i would do it

Comment: @MaylorTaylor you havent done any research before asking this, have you? Your post is not nicely formatted and its not clear... does that justify the downvote?

Comment: Did you lose reputation? Oh, look. You didn't. Check out how [meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) - though here, lack of research may be why the question got downvotes.

Comment: which post? this post is clear, concise, and well worded. It is direct and to the point. I knew that bounty was not refundable but i assumed i could at least give the bounty to the person who helped me with my question, even if it was indirectly.... also you WERE able to receive the bounty yourself, but that has been changed since i last encountered this situation.

Comment: "this post is clear, concise, and well worded." You're welcome ;)

Comment: @MaylorTaylor I disagree. Your question is not clear - I don't know whether you are asking about how the bounty system works or whether you are asking why a moderator did not see/respond to your bounty message?

Comment: No, there isn't any scraping of the site for the word "mod". If anything is very wrong on the site, e.g if there is offensive content, hate speech, spammer etc, or any other critical situation, users flag the posts. These go into a queue where moderators review each flag on a case by case basis. For situations like your bounty, or any other questions about the usage of the site, please come and ask here on meta. Meta voting doesn't effect your main site rep.

Answer (score 5):

If it isn't something that needs to be discussed privately, and is instead a general support question (like your example), you should ask here on meta.  If it needs to be discussed in private you can use the "contact us" link on the bottom of the page.

Comment: and before asking anything anywhere - search & research

Answer (score -14):

Flag your own message. That will get the MODS attention

Comment: Only involve a moderator if there is something serious going on - not when the info you are seeking is right there in front of you in the help centre that someone spent a good amount of time to put together....

Comment: Flagging is there to bring a problem to the attention of a moderator, not to ask support questions.  Mods cannot write an effective response to a flag to answer questions, not should they be answering questions of general support that doesn't need to be handled privately.

Comment: I see two downvotes on recent SO questions you asked. That could be a coincidence, or it could be the ["meta effect"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). People are not supposed to vote based on who asked a question, but before calling attention to yourself by posting on meta, it's a good idea to research your question thoroughly and make sure it hasn't been asked before. It's also a good idea to remove any language that could sound like a rant from your meta questions, since the community tends to receive such questions poorly.

Comment: (I'm not saying you posted a rant, just giving general advice about how to avoid the meta effect in the future.) One other method is to write only high quality questions on SO, so that even if you do trigger the meta effect, you will mostly get upvotes. ;) This is easier said than done, but you can always edit questions after posting them. You can also use downvotes as a hint that something may be wrong with your post and that it could use some editing love.