# Document how to contact a moderator

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators, user-experience

I would expect the help center to clearly and unambiguously identify some methods to contact a moderator.

This seems to be a recurring topic on meta -- users can't find out, so they ask; and are promptly told to flag something, and here's a downvote for your efforts. <sup>1</sup>

It would be less intimidating and frustrating if this were **spelled out** in the help center.

[Searching for "contact moderator" in the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=contact+moderator) brings up one promising page, and several possible secondary candidates somewhere down among clearly unrelated results;

1. [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)
2. [What if I need more help?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/more-help)
3. [Contact support](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) (just a contact form)
4. [What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

My suggestion would be to document this information in more detail in #4; to add "contact a moderator" to the dropdown list in #3; and link to these resources from #1 and #2.

Page #4 explains that you should flag the bad stuff, but it needs to be clearer -- when there is more than a single thing you want to flag, or the bad stuff isn't one of those things which has a friendly "flag me" next to it.

Text proposal:

> **How do I contact a moderator?**
>
> The usual way to contact a moderator is to flag problematic content.
>   If the content or behavior you want us to investigate is not in a place
>   where you can conveniently flag it directly, please flag something else!
>   A comment of your own will do fine, for example, if you cannot find
>   anything else to flag.

Maybe add this before the section about flagging.

Additionally, #4 should clearly be the number one search hit for this particular query.  (Not sure how to reliably fix that for at least the most common ways to phrase this.)

---

<sup>1</sup> See e.g. these questions.

- [How do I get a moderator's attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275430/how-do-i-get-a-moderators-attention)
- [What is the best way to contact a moderator privately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294695/what-is-the-best-way-to-contact-a-moderator-privately)

I agree that they are not excellent questions, but the fact that the user had to ask in the first place is the problem I am trying to address primarily.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305930/possible-spam-ring-too-much-going-on-to-describe-in-a-custom-flag/306023?noredirect=1#comment246831_306023 which is what prompted me to post this.

Comment: What might be worthwhile is seeing if this can't be put in the form of a proposed-faq as detailed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) (if you have the time or inclination to do so that is)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the pointer.  I'm thinking this should be in the general help section because it applies to all sites; but I'll certainly propose it as a FAQ for https://stackoverflow.com/ if this request doesn't take off.

Comment: I'd like to request that this potential faq include what to do if I catch someone serially reviewing badly.

Comment: Side note - you can't flag your own comments. We should probably be more specific in what exactly to flag under what circumstances when you can't directly flag what you want to.

Comment: I like Jon Clements' idea of adding the proposed-faq, but it's only helpful if you know about it. The help center is easier to find (I didn't know we had an FAQ until I saw this question)

Comment: curious why people would need to contact moderators directly?

Comment: @charlietfl When suspicious behavior was apparently deleted before you could flag it, for example. I think I've tried to find out how to contact a mod maybe twice (can't recall if I gave up, or posted on meta instead, or independently found a solution to whatever was the problem).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated the copy on the "What if I see someone doing something bad?" page to include the following:

> **Contacting a site moderator**
>
> The usual way to contact a moderator is to flag problematic content. If the content or behavior is not in a place where you can conveniently flag it directly, please flag any post by the user in question and leave a custom reason explaining what you think should be investigated.
>
> If the issue is too complicated to explain in a custom flag reason and you have sufficient reputation, you can try contacting the moderators in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com).

We're not going to add a "contact moderator" option to the contact form's drop down menu because moderators do not (and should not) have access to the email account used for all inquiries from this form. We have an "other" option that can be used by anyone who lands on that page but doesn't know what else to choose, and our full-time support staff will handle the case.

Comment: Thanks!  The chat link is a bit vague (I remember trying to find a room with a mod in it, and giving up) -- is there maybe a specific room you could link to?  ([Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)?)

Comment: @tripleee Tavern wouldn't work; most site mods are not there. The rooms associated with the site are still the best bet for finding a mod. Some sites (SU and Math) have a room specifically for contacting moderators; in others that role would be played by the "main" chat room.

Comment: @NormalHuman Oh, right, I see -- the link needs to be generic because it needs to work on all sites.